# How can i check, if BE user is logged in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

I know, that the old equivalent for this is:

```
[globalVar = TSFE : beUserLogin > 0]
```

That works till TYPO3 V8 like charm. Now i need this function (For some special features when BE User is logged in) in TYPO3 V9 and V10. Does somebody know how?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what your current TYPO3 version is and what didn't work after consulting the [changelog](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.4/Feature-85829-ImplementSymfonyExpressionLanguageForTypoScriptConditions.html) and [conditions reference](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#backend-user-isloggedin).

Comment: Im sorry, i will add it. Mainly im interested in V10 but also V9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `[backend.user.isLoggedIn]`. See the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#backend-user-isloggedin) for details.

Comment: That is strange. I've used that before and it didn't work. Now it works... Thanks!